# USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED Intent not firing

Tags: android, usb

Has anyone out there been able to get the android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" to work?

Ok so i'm trying to use the new usb host mode features to detect when a usb device is attached. For my purposes i want to be notified any time a device is attached. I was not able to see it happen. I'm using a broadcast reciever that i know works (when i have it listen for other things such as the home button being pressed. No matter what i try i can't seem to get the intent to fire.... So to make things simpler i decided to forget about my project and attempt to use google's own sample code and see if i could at least make that work. I don't have one of the missle launcher but i figured i could at least get it the USB_Device_Attached to fire. No go. I adapted the code to work for other devices. First i tried adjusting the device filter xml.
I added my device (a keyboard):

```
<usb-device vendor-id="1050" product-id="0010" />
```

I got the vendor and product from an lsusb command. When the device is attached the logcat shows that the device is found

```
D/EventHub(  144): No input device configuration file found for device 'Yubico Yubico Yubikey II'.
I/EventHub(  144): New device: id=43, fd=219, path='/dev/input/event8', name='Yubico Yubico Yubikey II', classes=0x80000003, configuration='', keyLayout='/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl', keyCharacterMap='/system/usr/keychars/Generic.kcm', builtinKeyboard=false
I/InputReader(  144): Device added: id=43, name='Yubico Yubico Yubikey II', sources=0x00000101
I/ActivityManager(  144): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/1 nav=1/2 orien=L layout=0x10000014 uiMode=0x11 seq=47}
D/MissileLauncherActivity(16191): intent: android.intent.action.MAIN
I/EventHub(  144): Removed device: path=/dev/input/event8 name=Yubico Yubico Yubikey II id=43 fd=219 classes=0x80000003
I/InputReader(  144): Device removed: id=43, name='Yubico Yubico Yubikey II', sources=0x00000101
I/ActivityManager(  144): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/2 orien=L layout=0x10000014 uiMode=0x11 seq=48}
D/dalvikvm(  144): GC_EXPLICIT freed 78K, 26% free 14717K/19719K, paused 3ms+3ms
D/MissileLauncherActivity(16191): intent: android.intent.action.MAIN
```

The xoom does find the keyboard and it is usable from the device (i can use it in the browser to type letters). And the intent sort of fires (but it only fires the android.intent.action.MAIN) i don't ever get the DEVICE_ATTACHED Intent. The log entry comes from the sample code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "intent: " + intent.getAction().toString());
```

In the resume function. After more digging and removing any reference to usb i found that every app i make get's the resume called when a keyboard is attached/detached (hence the intent: android.intent.action.MAIN log entry). 
    Right now the only thing i can figure is that it's a bug in the android source. 
By the way i'm using a wifi xoom with os 3.1.

Comment: I was about to recommend looking through the platform source code to figure out what it is really supposed to do... and then I remembered :-(   One idea though - do you have any USB gadget around that is not an HID device which you could try?

Answer (score 24):

I also had the same problem. I finally figured out that in the device filter xml we should add following line.

```
<usb-device vendor-id-"xxxxx" product-id="yyyyy">
```

the xxxxx and yyyyy should be decimal numbers. NOT HEX CODES. Then it all works as advertised!
I know it is late but I hope it helps.

Comment: Example:
`<usb-device vendor-id="0BDA" product-id="8187"/>` WRONG
`<usb-device vendor-id="3034" product-id="33159"/>` RIGHT

Comment: and vendor-id and product-id should be integer. don't use hex

Answer (score 16):

So I found a solution to my problem and I've learned a lot hopefully it can help someone else.

So first off **HID devices do not kick off any intent**. Nor do they show up in the `mUsbManager.getDeviceList()` list. Other things however do. I gave a usb memory stick a go and what do you know the device is listed in the device list. I also found out that the device returned does not have the a class,subclass, or protocol. Debugging revealed that the parent interface did however have the proper class/subclass/and protocol. 
Also if you must have a device filter. I ended up with a `class=0008 (USB STORAGE)` to work for my purposes. I'm guessing other classes would work as well.

So now on to figuring out intents. Turns out that the intent must be attached to a launcher activity. My attempts to attach it to a service or receiver will not bear any fruits. So now that I'm getting intents to fire I now see notifications popup when I attach my device (usb memory stick) it asks me to set my app as the default for that device. Perfect now my app gets run every time I attach that device. Note that you will be prompted for each unique device. But only once. It seems to be registered much like default programs.

Well, I think that about sums up what I found. too bad you can't get notified when an keyboard/mouse gets attached. Oh and one more thing. There are not any problems with the tiamat kernel, running it right now and no problems.

Comment: Yes, some HID devices do kick off an intent. (See the MissileLauncher sample application which uses an HID device). Devices that have their `InterfaceSubClass = 0x00` and `InterfaceProtocol = 0x00` cause an intent to occur. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 11):

I recently discovered a solution to a similar issue.

As someone has already noted, `HID devices` do not kick off an *intent*, which I think was your issue.

However, a related issue is that, if your program is set to run when a USB device is connected, then even once your application is running, you can't capture the `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` action. Instead, the system sees that intent, and says "oh that means this application wants to run (as declared in your manifest) and then it sends you the android.intent.action.MAIN action instead of the `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` action, and it calls `onResume()`. Even if your app is running. So as far as I can tell, you CAN'T capture the `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` intent if your manifest declares that your app will run when USB devices are attached. You just have to put some code in `onResume()` to check to see if USB is connected. Even if your program is running, onResume will get called again when a USB device is attached.

I note my solution in more detail here: [Android 3.1 USB-Host - BroadcastReceiver does not receive USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981736/android-3-1-usb-host-broadcastreceiver-does-not-receive-usb-device-attached/9814826#9814826)

Answer (score 3):

Enumerating devices

If your application is interested in inspecting all of the USB devices currently connected while your application is running, it can enumerate devices on the bus. Use the getDeviceList() method to get a hash map of all the USB devices that are connected. The hash map is keyed by the USB device's name if you want to obtain a device from the map.

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
```

If desired, you can also just obtain an iterator from the hash map and process each device one by one:

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
    UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next()
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My ultimate solution was to use the old fashioned polling technique. Here is a fairly minimal class which solves the problem to my satisfaction.

```
package com.YourCompancy.YourProduct;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;

import android.hardware.usb.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.os.*;

public class UsbDeviceWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED))
        {
            UsbDevice d = (UsbDevice)
                intent.getExtras().get(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            DeviceConnect(d, false);
        }
    }

    public void DeviceConnect(UsbDevice device, boolean Attached)
    {
            if (Attached)
            {
                            // Some suggestions ...
                            //    play sound effect
                            //    notify consumer software
                            //    determine if interested in device
                            //    etc
                            Log.i("usb", "device attached");

            } else
            {
                Log.i("usb", "device detached");
            }

    }

    public UsbManager manager;
    public Handler handler;

    public UsbDeviceWatcher(Context context, Handler handle)
    {

        this.handler = handle;

        manager = (UsbManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        IntentFilter dev = new IntentFilter();

        dev.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);

        context.registerReceiver(this, dev);    

        final UsbDeviceWatcher _this = this;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                LinkedList<UsbDevice> seen = new LinkedList<UsbDevice>();
                LinkedList<UsbDevice> attached = new LinkedList<UsbDevice>();

                            //there is a need for multithread support here
                                //   so the thread can watch for an exit condition
                while (true)
                {

                    HashMap<String, UsbDevice>
                        D = manager.getDeviceList();

                    for (UsbDevice d : D.values())
                    {
                        if (!seen.contains(d))
                        {
                            if (!attached.contains(d))
                            {
                                final UsbDevice dev = d;

                                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        DeviceConnect(dev, true);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            seen.add(d);
                        }
                    }

                    for (UsbDevice d : seen)
                    {
                        if (!D.values().contains(d)) seen.remove(d);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);  
                    } catch (InterruptedException exception)
                    {
                        return; 
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to use

```
new FileObserver("/dev/input") {
  @Override public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
     //gets called on input device insert / remove
  }
};
```

which will work for some usb devices (keyboard, mouse)

Comment: Is this works on non-rooted devices?

Answer (score 2):

I have my app set as `launchMode="singleTop"` and in that mode it seems like the `getIntent().getAction()` is always equal to the action that first started the app.

So if you start the app manually and *then* plug in a device (even after switching away from that app), you will receive `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

If you kill the app and then plug in the device, you will always get `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED`, even from switching away and back to your app, or even for *rotating the device*.

I actually weirdly receive intents when unplugging the USB device, which I don't think is documented - but of course I receive `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` when my device is detached.

Without `singleTop`, it does kind of work as expected, but then you get another stupid extra activity if your app is already open and you plug in the device.

Once again Android's API is buggy, overly complicated and difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

OK more work, more failure, but some progress.

I found out more from the sdk documentation. it appears that you have to have the device filter in order to use the intents. so I decided to try using a class filter instead of the vendor/product ids. I figure that it would be more general and hopefully catch the hid device. I used 03h as the class id , I tried various formats, I tried the subclasses, I even used lsusb to discover, class, subclass, and protocol of my device. these didn't seem to help at all. so I went further in to the sdk documentation and decided to try enumerating all of the devices to see what the os saw the class/subclass/protocol integers. I copied the code pasted it into the click listener and adding log.v statements. nothing shows in the logcat .

it looks, like the us system isn't seeing any device (even though the device actually works.) now this is very indicitive of the USB device connected intent not firing. now I must say that I am using a custom kernel in my xoom (tiamat). I thought this might have something to do with the problem a while ago, so I reverted to stock 3.1. and still now progress. now this was a while ago, before I tried enumerating, so now I will revert agaian and keep working with stock until I am sure the kernel is not the issue. I'll check back In when I found out more. success or failure. ofcourse if anyone else unterstands this better than me please chime in. 
one last note I'm a big worried about the whole otg host mode when I saw this in the documentation.. notice that the coe is identical even thought it references two methods of enumeration. probably just a copy writers mistake, but still worry some in light of all this failure.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to detect USB/Media Connect.

Manifest file

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".UsbReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I didn't do anything in the activity nor my receiver.

looks like this line is doing the stuff.

```
<data android:scheme="file"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect Usb Keyboard **WONT** fire **USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED**.

Instead, the System will fire **Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED**. However, as there is a configuration change, system will restart the Activity. You wont catch the action with the Activity restarted. In this case, you need to add **android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"** in your Android Manifest so that the Activity wont be restarted once a external keyboard is connected.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, Android **can** fire an intent when an HID device is connected. (The MissileLauncher sample application does just that. See the sample source code for more info.)

The Missile Launcher (Dream Cheeky USB Missle Launcher) HID Device has its subclass and protocol set to 0x00. For more info see: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/playing-with-a-usb-missile-launcher/

The caveat is that Android does not throw an intent for mouse and keyboard devices specifically (maybe more). I can however detect HID devices that have their InterfaceClass = 0x03, InterfaceSubClass = 0x00, InterfaceProtocol = 0x00. For my application, my HID device is an embedded controller so setting the subclass and protocol is not an issue.