# Can't see mouse and keyboard device with usbManager android

Tags: android, keyboard, usb, mouse, hid

I work on a project where I need get data of keyboard and mouse on a service. I also have to be able to send data to my device hid. To do this, I want use the usb host mode. When I get list of device, I can see a mass storage but no mouse and keyboard. After search, I have seen that usbManager don't return mouse and keyboard device. I have tried to change permissions (on  /system/etc/permissions) whitout success).
I have run the application [USB Device Info](https://github.com/alt236/USB-Device-Info---Android) and I see mouse and keyboard on linux device and not on android devices.

I use android 4.2.2.
Is it possible to get hid data of mouse (and keyboard) with usb host or I have to find an other way ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can detect mouse/keyboard via InputManager:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
    InputManager inptmgr = (InputManager)getSystemService(INPUT_SERVICE);
    int[] inputs = inptmgr.getInputDeviceIds();
    for(int i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
        String devicename = inptmgr.getInputDevice(inputs[i]).getName();
        if(devicename.toLowerCase().contains("mouse")) {

        } else if(devicename.toLowerCase().contains("keyboard")) {

        }
    }
}
```

As for any other data you may want to collect, you can browse all the other methods under `getInputDevice()` such as `getVendorId()`, `getProductId()`, `getMotionRange()`, `getKeyCharacterMap()`, and others.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see my device. Now the problem is to communicate with it. In fact, I think I rather need of UsbDevice.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for for a long time! I was confused by UsbManager recognizing one of the devices, and not recognizing the other, which I knew was working. I spent some hours trying to figure out what might be wrong with my code, or hardware. Now I tested it with InputManager, and it's found there!

Comment: Yes, InputManager will detect *all* inputs, including stylus. You can probably combine it with UsbManager to detect a usb drive *in addition to* the mouse/keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you can already use the HID device for input, it' working as a input device(keyboard or mouse) and you don't need to access it as a USB device. You can simply catch the input from the device via listeners such as OnKeyListener.

Comment: I can't use OnKeyListener because I have to get data on background service