# Receive intent ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED through code

Tags: android, android-intent, usb

I've run into a wall using the usb api. I am trying to use a broadcast receiver to receive the intent ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED but it will not.

To clarify I had this working great through the manifest but that created a new activity (and added to the back stack). I found this undesirable, especially given the nature of my app (a terminal).

My guess is that the device-filter xml metadata needs adding to the intent filter but I have no idea how.

Any feedback is welcome!

EDIT - some code.
Here is the juicy part from the manifest. Note that the intent filter is commented out in order to have a dynamically registered BroadcastReceiver pick up the intent (I assume you have to).

```
//<intent-filter>
//    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
//    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
//</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" 
android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>
```

Here is the code that hooks up my receiver

```
//register for attachment
IntentFilter attachedFilter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
registerReceiver(mUsbAttachedReceiver, attachedFilter);
```

This is the BroadcastReceiver declaration

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbAttachedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //BREAKPOINT HERE IS NEVER HIT
        String action = intent.getAction();
        showDebugToast(action);

        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device != null){
                    getDevicePermission(device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I avoided declaring a receiver in the manifest as I'm not totally sure about the practice to use there (the receiver exists seperate to any activity). Am I right in thinking the receiver will run as long as the application is running or is it foreground only even if declared in manifest? Any literature on this is appreciated.

I have since skirted around this issue by given the activity a 'singleTop' launchmode and implementing onNewIntent(). That gives me the behaviour I wanted while also allowing launches without the activity running (using manifest). This was my ultimate goal. However, I really wish to understand this behaviour and remain highly interested in a solution!

FURTHER EDIT: My debug device is a Samsung Galaxy S3. I have not changed the ROM.

Comment: have you declared a priority for your BroadcastReciever? please post the Reciever Part from your Manifest as well

Comment: I know this is very late but this appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981736/android-3-1-usb-host-broadcastreceiver-does-not-receive-usb-device-attached/9814826#9814826

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to add meta-data with Activity as:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
               android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
```

accessory_filter:

```
<resources>
    <usb-accessory manufacturer="Acme, Inc" model="Whiz Banger" version="7.0" />
</resources>
```

see this Android developer blog
[A Bright Idea: Android Open Accessories](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/05/bright-idea-android-open-accessories.html)

Comment: I should have been more clear. I already have a metadata section added but am unsure of if - in addition - i need to added it to the filter programatically.

Comment: @Gusdor checkout this http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/media/tests/CameraBrowser/src/com/android/camerabrowser/MtpClient.java maybe helpful

Comment: Hi imran. Thanks for the link. The registration and reception look very similar to my code samples posted above. Seems like it is pedestrian stuff but I'm obviously missing something.