# Detecting when a USB device is detached on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got an Android app that needs to detect when a USB peripheral is attached or detached. It works fine when the peripheral is first attached, but I don't receive any notification (i.e., I don't receive an `Intent` whose action is `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED`) when it is subsequently detached.

Here's the relevant part of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

It may also be worth noting that `LauncherActivity` only exists to start a `Service` when the device is attached, and to stop the service when it is detached. In either case, `LauncherActivity` always `finish`es itself immediately. All of this occurs in `LauncherActivity.onCreate`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/9814826/760489

Answer (score 18, accepted):

USB_DEVICE_DETACHED is a **broadcast** intent, thus you may want to declare the BroadcastReceiver in manifest with the appropriate intent-filter for detached action, also with meta-data attached.
Same goes for USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED, for who is interested.

Summary:
**USB_XXX_ATTACHED** is an activity intent
**USB_XXX_DETACHED** is a broadcast intent

(where XXX = DEVICE | ACCESSORY)

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

"There is no overlap within these messaging systems: Broadcast intents are delivered only to broadcast receivers, never to activities or services"

Comment: This is incorrect. The `DEVICE` actions are both broadcasts. For `ACCESSORY`, the attached is an activity action, but the detached in a broadcast action.

Comment: USB_XXX_ATTACHED intent can be used as broadcast intent also, I tried it and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 11):

Try with USB_STATE as below.

It will fire both attached and detatched to same receiver and in receiver you can identify whether is was attached or detatched event.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE");
```

Receiver:

```
public class USBReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected")) { 
             //do your stuff
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you

Comment: Thank you. But I'm getting false always. I'll check it.

Comment: @Hermandroid I imagine your situation would have been resolved by checking for `host_connected` instead (for future readers)

Answer (score 9):

So, I never got the `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` `Intent` to go to `LauncherActivity`; I don't know what the deal is there, probably something I don't properly understand about intent filters or the `Activity` lifecycle callbacks.

The solution I ended up using comes from the post linked by Pratik. I basically took everything about `USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` out of `AndroidManifest.xml`. Then, in the `onCreate` method of the `Service`, I registered a `BroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    detachReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED))
                stopSelf();
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(detachReceiver, filter);
}
```

A little clunky, and I'm still curious why just adding `USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` to the `<intent-filter>` of `LauncherActivity` wasn't working, but it does what I need.

Comment: Works great. The trick for me was removing the USB_DEVICE_DETACHED out of AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The fix that worked for me was to unregister in `onPause()` and register again in `onResume()`:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    stopIOManager();
    if(m_UsbReceiver!=null) unregisterReceiver(m_UsbReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    startIOManager();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(m_UsbReceiver, filter);
}
```

However, although the app seems to always receive the DETACH event, once in a while it doesn't get the ATTACHED event. I then need to plug and and unplug the USB connector, and it usually works after one or two attempts. I've put the blame of this strange behaviour on the OS, without certainty.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had this same issue because the activity is paused then resumed when the device is disconnected. 
Since the receiver is unregistered in the `OnPause()` method just prior to receiving the `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED`, your app never gets notified.

Comment: It'd be awesome if you posted how you got around this issue.