# Android: Receive UsbDevice from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, usb

I'm messing about with the USB host, and following the guidelines [on the Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) site I've managed to create a Hello World that starts up once a particular USB device is plugged in.  However, when I try and "...obtain the UsbDevice that represents the attached device from the intent" it returns null:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);


    // device is always null
    if (device == null){Log.i(TAG,"Null device");}
```

Here's my manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And my xml/device_filter.xml (I know these are the correct VID and PID because I've got a similar app working using the enumeration method described [on the Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) site):

```
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1234" product-id="1234"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: I am developing USB host communication, can i find you code somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

When your application is (re-)started due to the USB device attach event, then the device is passed on to the intent when `onResume` is called. You can get to it using the `getParcelableExtra` method. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        Log.d("onResume", "intent: " + intent.toString());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
            UsbDevice usbDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (usbDevice != null) {
                Log.d("onResume", "USB device attached: name: " + usbDevice.getDeviceName());
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround (or the intended usage?) thanks to [Taylor Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981736/android-3-1-usb-host-broadcastreceiver-does-not-receive-usb-device-attached?rq=1).  Basically, The way I understand it is that firing the intent that opens the application *only opens the application*.  After that you have to search for and access usb devices as per the [Enumerating Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#Enumerating-devices) section of the Android Developers page in the onResume method.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
                // Your code here!
        }
```

I'm not convinced this is the RIGHT way to do it, but it seems to be working.  If anyone has any further suggestions I'd be glad to listen.

Comment: To anyone experiencing this problem in **current year**, this snippet worked for me, while fredvanl's would always return a null device. I also created intent filters on main activity to no avail.
I am doing this on a Pixel C, SDK version 27 with a usb card reader.
`Log.i("DEVICE: ", device.getDeviceName());` -> /dev/bus/usb/001/026