# How to retrieve serialNumber corresponding to an USB device which is just connected

Tags: android, usb, usb-drive, usbserial

As an android developer, I want to retrieve serialNumber of USB Device which can be flash drive, mouse, keyboard which is just connected to an Android TV.

I read one can use [getSerialNumber()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice#getSerialNumber()) method
of UsbDevice class to retrieve this non-resettable identifier. But how to get the [UsbDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice) object corresponding to the device which is just connected.

I tried fetching the same using `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` android intent but found out the intent broadcasted is not being received by the system app. Same problem is [listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981736/android-3-1-usb-host-broadcastreceiver-does-not-receive-usb-device-attached) here as well.

Also, is there an way to retrieve the same without depending on the intent ?

- For example, to get the recently connected *storage volume*, one can use the [getStorageVolumes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#getStorageVolumes())() method which return an list. And then one can iterate over the list & get the first volume which is removable & this would be the flash drive which is recently connected.

```
public static String getPendriveDeviceId(Context context) {
    StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    if (storageManager != null) {
        StorageVolume[] storageVolumes = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
        for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
            // Check if the storage volume is a removable USB drive
            if (storageVolume.isRemovable()) {
                // Get the unique ID associated with the storage volume
                String deviceId = storageVolume.getUuid();
                return deviceId;
            }
        }
    }
    // Return null if no pendrive is found
    return null;
}
```

- But same logic doesn't work to fetch the UsbDevice object as [UsbManager.getDeviceList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager#getDeviceList()) returns an HashMap instead of an list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out what I was missing in the code due to which `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` intent was not being received. So, I added a `meta-data` field inside the receiver with the `device_filter.xml` file. And now with this change everything is working as expected.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.MediaMountedBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</receiver>
```

And the device_filter.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device/>
</resources>
```

Since, I wanted the logic to work for all usb device irrespective of the vendor & product id, I wrote `device_filter.xml` file in this way