# What Android tablets are developers using to writing & test USB Host apps?

Tags: android, usb, tablet, host

We're looking to start some development which will require USB Host functionality on Android. We were going to use the Samsung Galaxy 10.1, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534878/android-usb-host-problem-with-samsung-galaxy-10-1-tablet) suggests that Samsung have removed this api.

What tablets definitely have this working fully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US version of the Motorola Xoom Wifi-only (MZ604) is your best shot. This is a GDE (Google Device Experience) which means that it is a clean Android version. In other words Motorola has not done any modifications to Android and the USB-host API is intact.

Check my [thread](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/Xoom-3-1-and-USB-host/m-p/20680#M4443) on the motodev forum.

Comment: Marked as best answer, though not completely satisfactory from a UK dev standpoint...

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify the Samsung has removed the USB API from the Galaxy Tab 10.1 with OS 3.2, but I can verify that its full functionality is not present.

The Tab apparently has a special handler for HID devices, and a number of USB devices do not enumerate at all.

Answer (score 0):

I use two:

1. Google Galaxy Nexus OTG works, while I initially assumed it does not by using the wrong cable. There is OTG cable and there is micro USB device cable, both fit into connector but they are not the same.
2. Lenovo Thinkpad tablet just has the additional normal size USB connector, same as ordinary laptop. It is for USB host devices, and these devices work when connected.