# Which devices do and do not support USB Host mode?

Tags: android

Could someone please provide a comprehensive list of which devices do and do not support USB Host mode out of the box with no rooting, OS rebuilding, or cable hacking required?  I've read that only tablets support it.  Then I've read that the Droid supports it.  Many posts are a couple years old so not sure what is applicable now in March, 2012.  I've read that Windows phones support it?  Maybe its time to switch to that.  Does iPhone 4s support it?

Answer (score 7):

There is a pretty good chart, based on user submissions from actual devices here:

http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/

You can read the forum thread for more details on the methods for data collection:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1493325

Comment: There is something wrong with this chart, it is way too pessimistic. My Google Galaxy Nexus is shown as not supporting even when rooted when I know absolutely it does and even use USB to RJ45 converter with it. Maybe part of wrong diagnostic is due wrong micro USB to USB converters - also USB device to host converter fits into that port nicely but the attached USB device (the phone is host) does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I was also struggling to find which of the devices support USB hosting. After trying various devices it is clear that just having **Android 3.1 or higher** does **NOT** guarantee that your phone support **USB Hosting**.

I came across this  [Google Spread Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gcfug6m-2tHfiJFExV3gShsO10PgbuYvF36Q31-dOcY/edit#gid=1918400659) which lists various devices with USB Hosting.

You can also contribute to this list by submitting your responses through this [Google Form](http://goo.gl/Zp2svF).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

"Provide a comprehensive list?"  Pretty tall order there, pardner ;)

Nevertheless, support for USB Host Mode *is* available on Android 3.1 or higher:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

Here's an extremely interesting article about interfacing an Arduino to an Android:

http://createdigitalmusic.com/2011/05/android-adds-usb-host-mode-open-hardware-development-with-arduino/

And you can Google for specific Android 3.1++ devices that support USB Host Mode (including, of course, the Xoom tablet)

'Hope that helps

Comment: A tall order for you and me, yes, but not for Google or peripheral device manufacturers.  Here is a what I posted on Google forum: "Can someone from Google please provide a list of all devices that are running android 3.1 or higher?  Do these devices support USB Host mode?  The device must not require rooting, OS rebuild, or USB cable hacking to get it to work.  I want to buy or develop a receiver that connects to and collects data sent by peripherals over a low-power 2.4GHz signal and plugs into the device's USB port."  The arduino route, as I understand, uses USB Accessory Mode in which the

Comment: in which the plugged in device becomes the host and must then supply the power and have a microprocessor.  Starts to get non-mobile and a bulky contraption tethered to the smartphone.  I've not found a single phone runnng honeycomb (3.1), only tablets.  I see the Galaxy Nexus is running ice cream sandwich (4.0).  Does anybody know, have manufacturers enabled USB host mode on 4.0 devices?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have found a very helpful answer which worked for me (on Yarvik TAB464) and enabled a full USB host mode: [Android USB host and hidden devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices) - however I expect it to work on rooted tablets only :( (it seems that the Yarvik tablet comes pre-rooted).

OLD ANSWER: This is pretty frustrating. Many tablets claim to support USB HOST mode, but only a selected subset of the devices are supported: mouse, keyboard, mass storage and that's it. For example, http://www.yarvik.com/en/products/tablets/tablets_10/TAB464/ claims to support USB HOST mode; a mouse connected to the tablet works, but `owner.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.usb.host")` returns `false` and `UsbManager.getDeviceList()` returns always empty map, so it certainly does not support all USB devices (both 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 versions of Android provided by Yarvik). Installing Cyanogen on the device may perhaps help but this is something I would like to avoid, because of possible stability issues.

Also, Samsung Galaxy 10.1 Tablet does not work, according to [Android Usb Host Problem with Samsung Galaxy 10.1 Tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534878/android-usb-host-problem-with-samsung-galaxy-10-1-tablet)

There is only a handful of devices which actually support full USB HOST functionality out-of-the-box, but I have yet to see a complete, up-to-date list with all items actually verified. I confirm that the ASUS Transformer TF101 has full USB HOST mode, however I tested it on a rooted device only, not on the "vanilla" firmware.

Here is another list of devices with full USB HOST mode, but please take it with a grain of salt:

http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2114206

- The Toshiba Thrive has one full USB port.
- Lenovo ThinkPad Tablet has a full USB port.
- Acer Iconia Tab A500 one full USB port.