# Android USB host and hidden devices

Tags: android, api, usb, host

I am developing an Android application in which I have to communicate to an USB device. I tried to use standart google API in my app, but list of devices is allways empty.

Same things if i use USB device info with google api. List of devices searched by google api is empty,

lsusb gives following results:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2226:0014
```

my device is 2226:0014

log of eclipse:

```
I/USB3G(92): event { 'add', '/devices/platform/sw-ehci.1/usb2/2-1', 'usb', '', 189, 133 }
I/USB3G(92): path : '/sys/devices/platform/sw-ehci.1/usb2/2-1'
I/USB3G(92): VID :size 5,vid_path '/sys/devices/platform/sw-ehci.1/usb2/2-1/idVendor',VID  '2226
I/USB3G(92): '.
I/USB3G(92): PID :size 5,Pid_path '/sys/devices/platform/sw-ehci.1/usb2/2-1/idProduct',PID  '0014
I/USB3G(92): '.
I/USB3G(92): cmd=/system/etc/usb_modeswitch.sh /system/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/2226_0014 &,
I/USB3G(92): excute ret : 0,err:No such file or directory
```

If i plug in devices like rs232 adapters, bluetooth dongle, nothing happens,and there is no any result from API and lsusb.

Prtocol of a device is based on ezusb library.
Android v.:     4.0.3
kernel v.:      3.0.8
firmware build: crane_evb-eng 4.0.3 IMLK74k 20120330

Is there are any way to access hidden USB devices via API, or should i implement support of this device by writing driver and patching it into the firmware?

UPDATE: even if i create info file in *system/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/* with name 2226_0014
containing

```
DefaultVendor= 0x2226
DefaultProduct=0x0014
TargetVendor=  0x2226
TargetProductList="0014"
MessageEndpoint="0x00"
NeedResponse=1
CheckSuccess=20
```

i get the same error: "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To enable USB host API support you should add a file named
    **android.hardware.usb.host.xml**
and containing the following lines:

```
<permissions>
 <feature name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
</permissions>
```

into folder

```
/system/etc/permissions
```

in that folder find file named

```
handheld_core_hardware.xml or tablet_core_hardware.xml
```

and add

```
<feature name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

into `<permissions>` section.

Reboot your device. Usb host api should work.

Tested on CUBE U30GT with android 4.

Comment: @Greg-q : Where is handheld_core_hardware.xml or tablet_core_hardware.xml  located. I did't get these files.

Comment: After making these changes, DeviceList is still empty for me, even though I can see my HID device being connected when running dmesg

Comment: It should be stated that making these changes is only possible if  you are a ROM developer or if you have root and a writable (via remount) system partition, and only worthwhile if the hardware supports it.

Comment: @Droider how did you edit it? I am facing the same problem: read only file system

Comment: @Gaurav i had a rooted device so it did not made any issues for me.

Comment: does all this require root access?

Answer (score 6):

Excellent!  This worked on my Envizen V700NA running Android 4.0.4.

Minor Typo:  `<feature name="android.hardware.usb.host">`

Should be:   `<feature name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>`

Procedure:

1. adb pull /system/etc/permissions/tablet_core_hardware.xml
2. Update that file and create android.hardware.usb.host.xml as specified by Greg-q.
3. adb push android.hardware.usb.host.xml /system/etc/permissions
4. adb push tablet_core_hardware.xml /system/etc/permissions
5. Reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Worked like a charm on a micromax A120 canvas 2 phone (kitkat 4.4.2). now i can control my Arduino! i used busybox tools to do all the command line work (otherwise chmod wouldn't work). my steps (perhaps some were not required):

(0) install PDAnet drivers (http://pdanet.co/a/) on my Windows 8 computer.
(1) root the phone using Vroot (now called iRoot) at http://www.mgyun.com/m/en. Very simple, only catch is that the su grant/deny page is partly in chinese, no big deal.
(2) install busybox and jackpal's Android-Terminal-Emulator (see github https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator or play store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en )

(3) open a terminal window and become the superuser:

```
# su
```

(4) the file system may be read-only, so you might have to remount it:

```
# mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /
```

or

```
# mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /
```

or

```
# mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs rootfs /system
```

see http://www.pocketmagic.net/write-on-the-android-read-only-file-system/
also, see [Android 2.3 : Read-Only file system stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918456/android-2-3-read-only-file-system-stuck)
also, https://ckirbach.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/how-to-remount-system-as-read-write-in-android/

(5) make default.prop read/write:

```
chmod 666 /default.prop
```

(6) edit /default.prop, make the following changes:

```
ro.secure=0
ro.debuggable=1
persist.service.adb.enable=1
```

see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28653/obtaining-root-by-modifying-default-propro-secure
or http://bclary.com/blog/2014/04/14/splitting-and-packing-android-boot-images/

Finally, just for completeness, as the answer above says (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992683/979369):

(7) To enable USB host API support you should add a file named
android.hardware.usb.host.xml and containing the following lines:

```
<permissions>
 <feature name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
</permissions>
```

into folder

```
/system/etc/permissions
```

in that folder find file named

```
handheld_core_hardware.xml or tablet_core_hardware.xml
```

and add

```
<feature name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

into  section.

(8) Reboot your device. Usb host api should work.

Answer (score 1):

i've used adb on MK809, Android 4.1 Jelly Bean, and the command are:

adb remount /../../file.xml rw
adb push...

with normal command i'vent permission and the file is read only

Sorry for my bad english :P