# Interfacing 8051 microcontroller with android tablet via USB MIDI

Tags: android, usb, 8051

I want to send digital data from my android device to 8051 microcontroller via usb(from otg on my tablet to USB MIDI on 8051 board) which causes leds connected to the 8051 to blink...however when i tried to write the usb device detection code it did not work ..and i could not detect the 8051 MC.Could anyone  pls tell me how and where must i begin from.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure without more details. What is the device that you have? It is a tablet of some form but do you know whether host mode is enabled? How far have you got with the code?

If you have some code written to detect USB devices then I would use something like a USB mouse and see what happens. run `dmesg | grep usb` to see what the OS has to say when various devices are plugged in.

If the mouse is reported by the code then host mode support is enabled. If not, and especially if the OS still recognises it and you can move the mouse pointer etc. then there is a good chance that the host mode feature is not set properly.

If that is the case then follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices)