# Connect a USB device (smart card reader) on android

Tags: android, usb

I have some trouble to connect a USB smart card reader on my Android Tablet (ICS 4.0.3). This one not recognized the reader. I used "USB device info" application, and I saw that Linux system can see the reader, but not android system (using USB Host API)

I tried to connect it on my Galaxy Nexus (Jelly bean 4.1.1) and it worked

Could someone help me, I can understood why my phone recognizes it, but not the tablet

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the host feature may be disabled on your tablet.
I find this a little surprising as for the most part it tends to be enabled on tablets but I would certainly suggest that you check.

The following post is probably the best reference to look at as it is concise:
[Android USB host and hidden devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices)

You ought to be able to see this via adb shell or by downloading a terminal emulator from google play.

I had exactly the same symptoms on my Sony Xperia neo phone running CM9. The rom would see the device but the API would not. Even supported devices such as a usb mouse would be detected and working but unseen by the api. This might be an easy way for you to ttest my theory. Plug in a USB mouse, it should work, does the API see it? If not then the thread above almost certainly relates to your issue in my experience.

Comment: When I plug an USB mouse, it work but the API doesn't see it. I read the post you send me, but my tablet need to be "root" to edit file into /system, isn't it ?

Comment: As far as I am able to tell yes. If you do not want or are unable to root that deveice then you might want to contact the support team at the vedor and see whether there is any chance of that being enabled in an update. The trouble is that they are likely to tell you it is disabled because they do not support it. Unfortunately I do not know of any other way around this than to root if your device does not support it already.