# Host mode in a android device

Tags: android

Some days ago i bought a romanian android tablet EvoTab3 with Android version 4.0.3 and kernel version 3.0.8+. I want to connect some devices such as mouse, flash memory to this tablet that  will be the host station, using an OTG cable mini to mother a. I did the following steps:
1) USB debugging is ON
2) Download an app USB host controller that display the info:
   "S3C USB Host driver not found" " Root hub present, USB Host mode is active!"
3) I followed the steps from the post [Android USB host and hidden devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices).

I did not get any results, connected devices are not detected. 
 Please help me with this problem if you have some ideas.

Comment: hello and welcome to SO.you should be using http://android.stackexchange.com/ for such questions. questions on SO should pe related to programming.