# android.hardware.usb UsbManager class public methods getDeviceList and getAccessoryList return null

Tags: android, usb

I am trying to connect an Android phone via USB to an accessory (in this case a MacBook pro) and use getDeviceList() to verify that the connection is recognized and print the description of the UsbDevice object to the screen via toString() using the following code:

```
//as host
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
String s = "";
while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
   UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
   manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
   Log.d("List Devices", device.toString());

   s += device.toString();
}
```

The code sample came almost directly from the Android Developer site, but multiple phones do not seem to be recognizing any peripheral.  Similarly, I have tried treating the Android phone as the accessory, but am getting similar results.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Accessory Mode, from [Android Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html):

> USB accessory mode allows users to connect USB host hardware specifically designed for Android-powered devices. The accessories must adhere to the Android accessory protocol outlined in the Android Accessory Development Kit documentation.

Therefore, only devices that have implemented the AOA (Android Open Accessory) protocol will show up as a `UsbAccessory` from the phone.

As for Host Mode, the phone itself must have permitted it or else it will not really work. True, full support for Host Mode right out of the box seems very rare on most Android phones/tablets. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992683/155407) demonstrates how to get your phone/tablet to fully support Host Mode if it doesn't already, but note that this requires root access.