# getDeviceList() always gives empty in Android

Tags: android, usb, usb-hostcontroller

Working in Samsung S4 device, but not working in MotoG, Samsung A5(2016)

Below Code always return zero, I tried with giving permission in manifest file but still it returns null.. Can anyone give me any suggestion

In the Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devicelist = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = devicelist.values().iterator();
        Log.i("List", "size =" + devicelist.size());
        Log.i("List", "List" + devicelist);

        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            UsbDevice usbDevice = deviceIterator.next();
            Log.i("List", "Model     : " +usbDevice.getDeviceName());
            Log.i("List", "Id        : " +usbDevice.getDeviceId());

        }
    }

}
```

Manifest Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pathtech.usbapp" >

    <permission android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

manager.getDeviceList() always return zero Can anyone give me any suggestion? 
Log information gives like below:

```
09-12 23:26:28.692    5053-5053/com.example.usbapp I/List﹕ size =0
09-12 23:26:28.692    5053-5053/com.example.usbapp I/List﹕ List{ }
```

Please give me suggestions..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006889/usbmanager-getdevicelist-returns-empty

Comment: Are you trying to run this on an emulator?

Comment: No, using device only

Comment: Working in Samsung S4 device, but not working in MotoG, Samsung A5(2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me(for Samsung devices) thanku to @Gurupad Mamadapur,

To enable USB host API support you should add a file(xml file) and that containing the following lines:

```
<permissions>
 <feature name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
</permissions>
```

into folder(Location of the file)

```
/system/etc/permissions
```

in that folder find file named
handheld_core_hardware.xml or tablet_core_hardware.xml

and add

```
<feature name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

and
 Reboot your device. Usb host api should work.

Source: [Android USB host and hidden devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices/17036007#17036007)

But for Motog device still not detecting

Answer (score 0):

[Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#getDeviceList()):

> **getDeviceList()**
>
> Returns a HashMap containing all USB devices currently attached. USB device name is the key for the returned HashMap. The result will be `empty if no devices are attached, or if USB host mode is inactive or unsupported`.

Try adding this in your manifest file.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
    android:required="true"/>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26728839/3225001 provides details on how to check the usbhost capabilities of the device.

Comment: Same thing I tried.... it gives zero n empty list.... for size n device list respectively

Comment: Working in Samsung S4 device, but not working in MotoG, Samsung A5(2016)

Comment: Check this out : https://github.com/452/USBHIDTerminal/wiki/How-to-enable-USB-host-API-support and this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices/17036007#17036007.

Comment: Thanks, @Gurupad , For MotoG device still same problem