# UsbDevice returns zero size on Android Pie

Tags: android

Apps that use the USB OTG port under Android 7 work properly but fail on Android 9 returning `deviceList.size() == 0`. The port works fine for reading files from a memory card with apps from the Play Store.

The phone is a Huawei Mate 20 Pro (LYA-L29) Android 9.

Code is the usual:

```
manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    if (deviceList.size() == 0) {
```

etc

As mentioned, this worked properly under Android 7 (Samsung).

Comment: Your issue looks similar to answer by Alexey Sviridov here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006889/usbmanager-getdevicelist-returns-empty

Comment: Thank you, you're correct! But I don't know if this is an Android or manufacturer fault.

Comment: looks mostly like hardware issue. try for android 9 with other device