# Android 2.3 : Read-Only file system stuck

Tags: android, linux, shell, permissions, adb

### Hi. I have an LG-Optimus HUB E510 Android Device.

Two weeks ago I rooted my device to access internal storage and change some files (such as alarms, notifications, sounds, .etc).

Well I did it. But after re-storing factory settings, internal storage files became again read-only.

Then I tried adb-shell to change the privileges of folders and files with

```
chmod  777  "folder destination"
```

but the shell responded as

> **Unable to chmod** system/media/audio/alarms: **Read-only file system**

Now I don't know what to do. So, I need your suggessions. Thank you.

---

**Pictures**

This is the changing permission attempt from shell in ubuntu
[image: This is the changing permission attempt from shell in ubuntu]
The files included with current permissions in eclipse DDMS perspective
[image: The files included with current permissions in eclipse DDMS perspective]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for programming questions. This is not a programming questions. You might have more luck posting your questions in a forum supporting the tools you used to root your device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use one of the following ways:
`mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /system`
or
`mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs rootfs /system`

You also can use it for any folder that you need even root (`/`)

Comment: Thanks. The second command worked for me.

Comment: Note that this is only a momentary fix; it will revert every time the phone reboots, as the startup script mounts the partition read only.  Leaving it writable isn't really necessary - anything that depends on that is probably not the right way to solve whatever problem is trying to be solved.

Comment: `mount: Operation not permitted`  I guess the device needs to be rooted?

Comment: @StijndeWitt Yes, It was in question: "Two weeks ago I rooted my device to access internal storage ...."

Comment: Doesn't work: mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /system
mount: Read-only file system

Comment: Doesn't work: **mount: Invalid argument**

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
adb root
adb remount
```

and this will also mount /system