# USB Host getDeviceList return empty

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

My device - Nexus 5 with 4.4.4

Here is my code

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Log.e(TAG, "get device list  = " + deviceList.size());
Toast.makeText(this, "get device list  = " + deviceList.size(), 200).show();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
   UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
   Log.e(TAG, "device name = " + device.getDeviceName());
}
```

But, always return empty. i try to root my device. Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices/11992683#11992683). But, i plug mouse and keyboard with OTG cable to Nexus 5. it does not work. 
Any idea how to solve it?

Updated:
I try USB card reader and USB Camera. It can detect them. Does Android filter USB mouse and keyboard devices?

Comment: Does a USB mouse get you a mouse cursor? (It does on my host-capable phone) If the device is claimed by the OS like that, it may not show in the USB host API.

Comment: Yes. It shows a mouse cursor. Except mouse and keyboard, do you know devices is detected by OS but not show in USB host API?