# Android : Can we read the file from USB?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-ndk

I want to read a pdf(or text) file stored in USB flash drive(pend drive) in my android application.

Is it possible using Android API ?

Any code snippet or link would help me.

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: if you mean to read a file that is on a USB drive connected to the same computer, I'm afraid the answer is probably NO.

Comment: I will connect my USB drive with my Android phone and I want to access the file on that USB drive using Android SDK in my application. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please look at that [android-serialport-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of [USB Host Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) which only available from Android 3.1 and above. Although having a device which supports USB Host Mode is a separate matter. See this SO question, especially the last answer: [Which devices do and do not support USB Host mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765207/which-devices-do-and-do-not-support-usb-host-mode)