# Connecting USB device to Host of Android Tablet

Tags: android, camera, usb, host, galaxy-tab

I want to connect an USB camera (camera for industrial use, no consumer camera) to my Android Tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1n). I' bought the original USB adapter from Samsung. When I connect the camera I get the message "unknown USB device".
In the API of google there is an intent filter example which I had tested with my device. I can't communicate with the camera. I can't see any endpoint or vendor and product id.
Is there any app which tells me which USB devices are connected and show their pid and vid like device manager in windows?

I've read something about a whitelist. For using my camera is it necessary to add my product and vendor id?

I've installed the app "USB Device Info" which doesn't show my device. The app "DSLR Controller" works perfectly with my Canon 7D.

Is there no chance to connect my device to tablet?:
[Android Usb Host Problem with Samsung Galaxy 10.1 Tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534878/android-usb-host-problem-with-samsung-galaxy-10-1-tablet)

Thanks,
lumapu

Comment: To simply find the VID/PID (to research how to talk to it) plug the camera into a desktop.  For testing how far Android is getting in handshaking with it, you probably need to get adb up and running over wireless, or run an ssh server from adb-over-usb, then disconnect the adb, ssh into the tablet, plug in your camera, and run dmesg at the command prompt (you can also try using a terminal program on the device).  You do realize you will need to do quite a bit of custom programming to make this work, unless you find an application that specifically supports whatever this camera talks.