# Registering application to handle USB device attachment

Tags: android, usb

I want to add my application to the list of apps Android offers to launch when a digital camera is connected. I've added this to my manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />

  <meta-data
     android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
     android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</intent-filter>
```

And specified a filter (class 6 is digital camera, but I've tried empty filter as well):

```
<resources>
    <usb-device class="6"/>
</resources>
```

It has no effect, my app is still not in that list. What else do I have to do?

Note that I'm not interested in the broadcast intent, all I need is to make it to the list of choices for handling the device user is presented with.

Comment: Perhaps this can be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163856/usb-device-attached-intent-not-firing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Manifest should be like this:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
   android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
   android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
```

I. e. `meta-data` shouldn't be sub-element of `intent-filter` like I've put it.