# BroadcastReceiver onReceive() not called when Google Glass is connected to Android device

Tags: android, android-intent, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to connect Google Glass with an Android device over USB. But when I connect them over USB, the Android device is working fine and its `BroadcastReceiver onReceive()` run, but on the other hand Google Glass `BroadcastReceiver onReceive()` method never get called.

The code that works is below:

in onResume() :

```
 registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new intentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED));
```

Broadcast:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbDeviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            // some code...
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            // some code...
        } else {
            // some code...
        }
    }
    };
```

Below is the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.usb.glass"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.usb.glass.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>


        <!-- <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />  -->
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help?

Comment: are you trying to broadcast from one app running in one device to one app running in the other one??

Comment: @eduyayo       no. Normally broadcast run when USB device is detected. But in my case its not fired.

Comment: what about device filter?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163856/usb-device-attached-intent-not-firing

Comment: I tried but not working...